# Are other classes able to access the webdriver instance when extending test base class? Getting NullPointerException Error

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, java, grid

I am getting this error when running the below selenium scripts using TestNG with Selenium Grid. I'm extending the testbase class to access the WebDriver, but I'm not sure if each class is getting the WebDriver instance correctly since I'm getting a `NullPointerException`?

The tests scrolls to the first item to click and doesn't click it. I'm new to Java, please advise. I am wondering if I'm understanding inheritance and initiation of objects correctly. Thanks for your help.

> java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agree with @Dale Emery.

Use this code:

```
public class WatchTV {

    WebDriver driver;
    WebDriverWait wait;
    int waitseconds = 60;

    public WatchTV(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, waitseconds);
    }

    By watchtvlink = By.linkText("Watch TV »");

    public WebElement WatchTVLink()
    {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(watchtvlink));
        return driver.findElement(watchtvlink);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I'm new to coding. I've been stuck on this for awhile. Thank you.

Comment: If I have multiple methods in WatchTV class, how can I use WebDriverWait in all the methods without having to copy the same code into each method? Thanks.

Comment: I changed my answer according to your question

Answer (score 2):

Your `Setup()` method runs (and initializes the driver) only in the `Pg_WatchTV_Test` class.

Merely extending `TestBase` does not cause TestNG to run your setup method. It runs setup methods (annotated by `@BeforeMethod` and the like) only if the class has test methods.

Your `WatchTV` class has no tests, so `TestNG` does not treat it as a test class. So the `Setup()` method in `WatchTV` never runs. So your `WatchTV` instance has no driver.

Rather than making `WatchTV` extend `TestBase` to get a driver:

1. Write a `WatchTV` constructor that takes a `WebDriver` parameter.
2. Do one or the other of:

   - Create the `WebDriverWait` instance in the constructor, using the passed driver.
   - In the constructor, save the driver to a field. Then in the `WatchTVLink()` method, create the `WebDriverWait` instance using the driver field. (See kotoj's excellent example.)

Comment: The same answer I've just written in the same time, but without example code, so I posted also my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I'm new to coding. I've been stuck on this for awhile. Thank you.

Comment: If I have multiple methods in WatchTV class, how can I use WebDriverWait in all the methods without having to copy the same code into each method? Thanks.